# IntelliJ remove search results from the search list

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to remove some of the results from the list of "Find Occurrences of XZY" just like in Eclipse?

There is an "Exclude" option that scratches them off but that isn't at all as clean. Under Eclipse, I was quite used to being able to do so, especially when finding lots of results in the code, some in external libraries, some in places I don't want to modify, so in the end I'm left with few things I can review and be done with...

For example, the following search finds 679 occurrences, out of which only 7 are in my codebase, rest is under logs or external libraries (which sometimes I might want to be able to search, but not this time).

[image: Example...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NOT possible as per the documentation available

[image]

It may be possible to write a plugin, but I doubt whether it is worth the effort. I would rather filter the results before the results are delivered using "Scope" section of the "Find in path" to exclude the unwanted libraries.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of `PHPStorm 2016.1` (at least), it is now possible.
[image: Remove result from search]